# Hyperlink against image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, prettyphoto

Im pretty new with JQuery and thought to try some design tasks. I read a few articles to get grips with the foundations and have come across a little snag.

What i am trying to do is rotate some images. I managed to achieve this by using the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ animationSpeed: 'slow', slideshow: 5000, timeout: 2000 });

api_images = ['myimage1.jpg','myimage2.jpg'];
api_titles = ['',''];
api_descriptions = ['','']
$.prettyPhoto.open(api_images,api_titles,api_descriptions);

}); 
</script>
```

So the images are showing/rotating which is great but im struggling to get each image to have an individual hyperlink so clicking the image would take them to the relevant page.

I have tried:

image_markup = 'Link' but doesnt work.

Ive tried adding the a tag to the api_titles value but that didnt work either.

Could anyone advise how to achieve this?